# Table view is not popping up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have this TableViewController (interface builder object hooked by  IBOutlet sideTable) in my SideBarViewController's class xib file that I am trying to populate in my ViewController (kind of like Facebook' App side menu). For some reason I cannot get this to work. It works fine if I make the SideBarViewController class a sub class of tableviewcontroller and progmatically  customize the tableview in its implementation file. But I rather use the xib. Any tips will be appreciated.

ViewController.h

```
      @property (nonatomic, strong) SidebarViewController *leftSidebarViewController;
```

ViewController.m

```
  - (UIView *)viewForLeftSidebar {
// Use applicationViewFrame to get the correctly calculated view's frame
// for use as a reference to our sidebar's view
CGRect viewFrame = self.navigationController.applicationViewFrame;
UITableViewController *controller = self.leftSidebarViewController.sideTable;
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewFrame.origin.y, 270, viewFrame.size.height);
controller.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
return controller.view;
 }
```

SideBarViewController.h

```
      @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableViewController  *sideTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out these steps

1) Change your SidebarViewController.h so that it may look like

```
@interface SideBarViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource ,     
 UITableViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic , weak) IBOutlet UITableView *sideTable;
```

2) In `SideBarViewController.xib` , hook view of `SideBarViewController` with `UIView` . view should not be hooked with `UITableView`. For tableView , use a separate outlet like in step (1).

3) Your method `viewForLeftSideBar` would look like

```
- (UIView *)viewForLeftSidebar {
CGRect viewFrame = self.navigationController.applicationViewFrame;
// Assuming that self.leftSidebarController is already initialized up above.
if(self.leftSidebarViewController == nil){
self.leftSidebarViewController = [[SideBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideBarViewController" bundle:nil];
}

self.leftSidebarViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewFrame.origin.y, 270, viewFrame.size.height);
self.leftSidebarViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
return self.leftSidebarViewController.view;
 }
```

I Hope it would help you out.